# Extending template blocks in Phoenix framework for custom css/js in the templates

Tags: templates, view, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a view that needs custom javascript for this specific page, so I don't want to append a `script` tag in the layout because it would load that script for all the pages.

Other template engines like django have the concept of blocks, but I guess this doesn't fit in the functional approach of elixir.

This is an example for django:

**base.html** <- This would be the layout, like `templates/layout/app.html.eex` in Phoenix

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block js %}
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**page1.hml** <- This is like `templates/module/index.html.eex` in Phoenix

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    Content of the page 1 with some kind of gallery or whatever...
{% endblock content %}

{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="script_only_for_page1.js"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

**Final render**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Content of the page 1 with some kind of gallery or whatever...

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="script_only_for_page1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How could achieve this result using Phoenix?

*Note that the same could be required for custom css in the `head` tag for certain pages.*

Comment: Please see the render_existing section of the answer I linked, it seems like the same use case.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! sorry I didn't find that before asking.